# Hadoop 2.7.1 installation no bashrc?

Tags: bash, hadoop

Im trying to install Hadoop 2.7.1 on my current laptop running linux mint 17 right now following this guide: http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-single-node-cluster-on-centos-redhat/#

However, when I am on step 4 i get:

$ ~/.bashrc
-su: /home/hadoopdev/.bashrc: No such file or directory

or when i try: $ vi .bashrc

it shows an empty window with ~ on the side

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing. `~/.bashrc` just doesn't exist yet, so you can create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 4 just says edit and append those lines at the end of the file.

There is not a problem if the file does not exist. Just open in up and insert those lines, then save.